# Is there any way to map a list of elements to a dictionary without a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, mapping

I want to create 2 dictionaries by mapping 2 lists from a central dictionary, without using a loop.

Input dictionary:

```
edict_all = { 1:[[23,20]], 2:[[45,45]], 3:[[56,43]], 4:[[66,23]], 5:[[24,23]], 9:[[57,78]], 8:[[67,76]], 51:[[242,223]]}
```

And I have 2 lists:

```
list_a = [1,4,8,9,51]
list_b = [1,2,3,5,9]
```

Currently, I am using 2 for loops:

```
edict_a, edict_b = dict(), dict()
for i in list_a:
    edict_a[i] = edict_all[i]

for i in list_b:
    edict_b[i] = edict_all[i]
```

And the output is:

```
edict_a = {1: [[23, 20]], 4: [[66, 23]], 8: [[67, 76]], 9: [[57, 78]], 51: [[242, 223]]}

edict_b = {1: [[23, 20]], 2: [[45, 45]], 3: [[56, 43]], 5: [[24, 23]], 9: [[57, 78]]}
```

Comment: Not aware of a way to get what you are looking for without python looping through the values. There are lots of ways to get what you want with list or dict comprehensions as well as built-in functions that may not have the appearance of the looping approach you are using (and may be more efficient) but in fact are all looping through the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loops at some level are unavoidable here, but you can hide them with `zip` and `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

edict_a = dict(zip(list_a, itemgetter(*list_a)(edict_all)))
edict_b = dict(zip(list_b, itemgetter(*list_b)(edict_all)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to filter data and then pass it back to `dict()` constructor:

```
edict_a = dict((key, value) for key, value in edict_all.items() if key in list_a)
edict_b = dict((key, value) for key, value in edict_all.items() if key in list_b)
```

And yes, loops in any form are unavoidable for this problem. At least you can write it in one line.